# How to delete sixth answer from stackoverflow of our own

Tags: discussion

Today I was deleting some of my answers on StackOverflow. After deleting 5 answers it started giving me an error stating that :

> You have already deleted 5 of your own posts today; further deletes are blocked

So my question is, how can we delete more than 5 answers in a day? Also, why is there a limit of only 5 answers to delete.

Comment: Why are you deleting your answers?

Comment: @hims056 Because they are not useful.

Comment: If you delete more answers, you may [get ban on answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/187824).

Comment: @hims056 Means If I delete my answer everyday. I will get ban on answering?

Comment: It doesn't depend on days, it depends on amount of deleted answers. Read the post given by me.

Comment: @hims056 thanks I will never delete my answer. And keep in mind that answer only relevant things.

Comment: Uh, that seems a bit of a stretch. You don't have to *never* delete answers again. Just don't delete *so many* of them.

Comment: There is a limit in place to prevent rage-quitting. Why do you need to delete more than 5 answers? You can always delete more tomorrow anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I will keep that in mind..:)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually I was wondering that why there is a limit for deleting our own answers.

Answer (score 6):

There is a limit in place to prevent people from rage quitting.

A rage quit is when someone is so upset over something that happened to them on the site that they decide to stop playing and take their ball home with them, and attempt to delete everything they ever posted.

The problem with that is that when you post an answer, you license it to the site under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) (See also: "[Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow have moved to CC BY-SA 4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/282094)").

You cannot rescind that license by deleting everything.

You can always delete an answer you feel is not up to standard, but you rarely need to delete more than 5 in a day. If you run into that limit, perhaps you need to rethink how you answer and not post the answers you are now unhappy with in the first place.